# confused by C# type conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm new to C# but familiar with vb.net

my setVendor functions expects an int and a string

why does this work

```
shopify.setVendor(System.Convert.ToInt32(reader["ProductID"]), System.Convert.ToString(reader["Vendor"]));
```

but this fails for both parameters:

```
shopify.setVendor(int.Parse(reader["ProductID"]), reader["Vendor"].ToString);
```

very confused. It wants a string and I give it a string but it doesn't accept it . . . error converting string to int

Comment: to whoever voted me down. I spent significant time on this before i posted. Along with ToInt32 and int.Parse I tried (int)reader["ProductID"] as well. I guess you just can't please some people. I've been doing VB for 20 years, but decided to write my first application in C#. I'm reading a "C# and VB.NET Conversions" book, but sometimes it's hard to spot your errors especially in a new language.

Comment: Not that I'm the downvoter, but *any* time you say "this fails" you should give the precise failure mode - including the exception or compile-time error.

Comment: @JonSkeet I appreciate the time and effort you took to write your answer, but I guess I should remove it since it's downvoted and there are two calls to close it, right?

Comment: You can't delete the question now, as it has an upvoted answer. You can still improve it by showing the error messages you received with the previous code though - that may even make the downvoter change their mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an overload of `Convert.ToInt32` which accepts `object`. There's no such overload for `int.Parse`. The argument must be a `string` *at compile time*. You would need:

```
shopify.setVendor(int.Parse(reader["ProductID"].ToString()),
                  reader["Vendor"].ToString());
```

(Note the change from `ToString` to `ToString()` for the second argument... previously you were specifying the `ToString` method group which is used to create delegates; with the change you're *calling* `ToString` instead.)

Or:

```
// This only works if the value *is* a string
shopify.setVendor(int.Parse((string) reader["ProductID"]),
                  reader["Vendor"].ToString());
```

Ideally, however, you'd get back the values in the correct forms already, so you could use:

```
shopify.setVendor((int) reader["ProductID"], (string) reader["Vendor"]);
```

Or:

```
// Set up productIdColumn and vendorColumn first
shopify.setVendor(reader.GetInt32(productIdColumn), reader.GetString(vendorColumn));
```

Also note that `setVendor` is not a conventional .NET method name.

Comment: ah I see, basically it's because I was missing () on ToString arg! C# takes a lot of getting used to!
Cheers!

Comment: @MaxHodges: No, that was only *one* error. The *other* error was that you were calling `int.Parse(reader["ProductID"])` which wasn't going to work...

Answer (score 1):

Well, for your first question

`System.Convert.ToInt32(...)` and `System.Convert.ToString(...)` convert the supplied arguments to `int` and `string` respectively which is in the correct format as expected by your code.

Secondly, it should be `ToString()` not `ToString` since you want to make a *call* to the method:

```
reader["Vendor"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

The ToString part in your second code-snippet requires parentheses () because it is a method, not a member or property.

Answer (score 1):

```
int productId;
if(int.TryParse(reader["ProductID"].ToString(), out productId))
   shopify.setVendor(productId, reader["Vendor"].ToString());
```

Would be a safe way to do it.